# DropWhile to extract between two specific lines

Tags: python, python-itertools

practising using DropWhile in Python, and have hit a bump.

For example if this is line in a file:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test5
Test6
Test7
Test8
Test9
Test10
```

And I want to pull out the lines between Test5 and Test8.

I know how to do this another way (for line in file...get the last number of line...if line > 5....if line < 8...print); but I specifically want to practise using DropWhile.

I tried this a few different ways but I can't seem to get it to work:

e.g.

```
dataset = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
def print_out(line):
    if int(line.strip()[-1]) > 5:
        if int(line.strip()[-1]) < 8:
            return True
        else:
            return False

for line in dropwhile(lambda line: print_out(line) == True, dataset):
    print line.strip()
```

This doesn't work, all lines are printed out.

Another way I tried to use a long lambda expression in the dropwhile line instead of using a separate function, but when I did something like this:

```
for line in dropwhile(lambda line: 5 < int(line.strip()[-1]) < 8, dataset):
```

This code works if I only have one expression (i.e int(line.strip()[-1]) > 5 or int(line.strip()[-1]) < 8, but not both).

I'm wondering if someone could show me a pythonic way, using DropWhile, to pull out the lines between Test5 and Test8 in my test data set?

Answer (score 2):

`DropWhile` is not what you need, from a functional aproach you have to use filter:

```
filter(lambda line: 5 < int(line.strip()[-1]) < 8, dataset)
```

DropWhile will stop once the condition is reached one time, so the list will continue to have the rest of the values once it reach `Test6`

Comment: Alternatively, iterating over a generator expression: `for line in (line for line in dataset if 5 < int(line.strip()[-1]) < 8):`

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use `dropwhile()` on your dataset, then you need to also make use of `takewhile()` to grab the required lines as follows:

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile


for line in takewhile(lambda x:  int(x.strip()[-1]) < 8, dropwhile(lambda x:  int(x.strip()[-1]) <= 5, dataset)):
    print line.strip()
```

This would give you:

```
Test6
Test7
```

So it works in two steps, first dropping each line until the required start point, and then only taking lines until the required end point, at which point it completes.